# is there a way to fetch the color code of a cell in excel using a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, excel, rubygems

[image]

I am parsing an excel using Ruby and been using [Roo gem](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) for a while and it works great. Now, I am having troubles how to fetch the cell color, is it possible?

Most of the gem I found that use excel cell color formatting are just for writing spreadsheets not reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Roo gem has it (seems like there was [an attempt](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/pull/300) 4 days ago, but it wasn't merged, and the contributor closed the PR).

You could use the [Spreadsheet gem](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet) instead to fetch the background color.

```
# get bg color at 1st Sheet, 3rd row, 5th column.
# I didn't run this.. go to gem repository for more accurate examples?
book = Spreadsheet.open '/path/to/an/excel-file.xls'
sheet = book.worksheet(0)
row = sheet.row(2)
cell_format = row.format(4)
color = cell_format.pattern_bg_color
```